# Gif animation from 383 .gif's

Tags: objective-c

I've created an gif animation in adobe flash, now I wanna import it in Xcode to put it into my app. I have 383 gif images (frames), and I have written this code to create a smoothly flow animation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#define IMAGE_COUNT       383




@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController




- (void)viewDidLoad
{

            [super viewDidLoad];

    //////////////////


    // Build array of images, cycling through image names
    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
     imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"picollage00%d.gif", i]],nil];


    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 5;
    [imageView startAnimating];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

The images are like this and then the images are counting up to picollage0383.gif

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you've a question you'd like to ask?

Comment: yup i want to het the answer how I can do this

Comment: What you do is creating an new `NSArray` every time you loop. What you want to do is creating an `NSMutableArray` outside the loop and calling `[mutableArray addObject:[UIImage ...]]; sorry For not providing a full answer but I am on mobile ... Hope you get the idea ;)

Comment: because this code doesnt work

Comment: mm, can you please give a full answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code is another semantic error: You start with image `picollage000.gif` but it should be `picollage0001.gif`, shouldn't it?
I changed that using the if-clauses and another condition in the for-loop.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#define IMAGE_COUNT 383

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    // Start with image picollage0001.gif
    for (int i = 1; i <= IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
        if (i < 100)
            if (i < 10)
                [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picollage000%d.gif", i]]];
            else [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picollage00%d.gif", i]]];
        else [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picollage0%d.gif", i]]];

    // Assuming `animationImages` is an NSArray
    imageView.animationImages = [imageArray copy];
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 5;
    [imageView startAnimating];
}
```

Above is tested code (the loop) and it generates the correct filenames and stores the initialized `UIImage`s in an `NSMutableArray`.

*Note: Depending on how large your `gif`s are this might be a bad idea (huge memory allocations) to put all the images in an array. If it is a slow animation you should load the images just before you need them and dealloc them after using them immediately.*

Comment: this doesn't works, there are many syntax errors

Comment: Yeah, as I said I am on iPhone and I didn't want to post an answer therefore ... However, I am sure you are able to fix them ;)

Comment: Can you post it later?

Comment: @user2332018: Have a look at my edited answer! That's working for me and so it should for you. If not or if you have any questions let me know ;)