# PNG image sequence animating error

Tags: objective-c

I want to make an animation from 385 png images, i've written some code and you can see it below. Xcode is whole the time giving the "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error...

I have a big list of the png images (the frames) which are counting from "picollage 01" to "picollage 385"

My code:

```
#define IMAGE_COUNT  385

 NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    for (int i = 1; i <= IMAGE_COUNT; i++)

            if (i < 100) {
                [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picollage 0%d.png", i]]]; }
            else {
                [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picollage %d.png", i]]];}

    animatview.animationImages = [imageArray copy];
    animatview.animationRepeatCount = 1000;
  [animatview startAnimating];
```

Comment: [Why did you make a new account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633862/gif-animation-from-383-gifs/16634080#16634080)

Comment: Have you tried `[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picollage 0%d.png", i] stringByStandardizingPath]]];`?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676947/png-image-sequence-error ... Why do you do that?

Comment: Please don't repost here. Editing your question to clarify or add details will bump it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the cause of your issue `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0]`, that should be `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:IMAGE_COUNT]`

Comment: Nope ;) `initWithCapacity:0` is used for better performance ;)

Comment: @HAS As Apple Document said https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html
instance method `- (id)initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems`
`Return Value
An array initialized with enough memory to hold numItems objects. The returned object might be different than the original receiver.`

Comment: You are right, but also read the discussion part ;) `Mutable arrays expand as needed; numItems simply establishes the object’s initial capacity`